# Notification nodejs

Tags: node.js, notifications

I use notification in my Web application (nodejs), every time when i refreshe ***my page /notes*** i click on my notification and in console i have the message toto. My probleme is : if i refresh seven times my page, in console i have seven messages toto. How can i resolved this probleme.

Thanks

Code :

```
router.get('/notes', passportConfig.isAuthenticated, function(req, res) {

notifier.notify(
    {
        title: 'My awesome title',
        message: 'Hello from node, Mr. User!',
        icon: path.join(__dirname, 'coulson.jpg'), 
        sound: true, 
        wait: true 
    },
    function(err, response) {
        // Response is response from notification
    }
);

notifier.on('click', function(notifierObject, options) {
    console.log("toto");
});   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

notifier.on(...) is an [event listener](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/events.html). Once is iniciated it will be active until you remove event listener.

Problem is with your function scope. `notifier.on()` event listener should be iniciated only once.
Try pull off `notifier.on()` logic from router.get() function scope. 
Every time you reloaded page that created another one event listener :)

```
notifier.on('click', function(notifierObject, options) {
    console.log("toto");
}); 

router.get('/notes', passportConfig.isAuthenticated, function(req, res) {

notifier.notify(
    {
        title: 'My awesome title',
        message: 'Hello from node, Mr. User!',
        icon: path.join(__dirname, 'coulson.jpg'), 
        sound: true, 
        wait: true 
    },
    function(err, response) {
        // Response is response from notification
    }
);  
});
```

Comment: @valentin-valentyn please accept my answear if it help:)